# Countable subadditivity of seminorm in $c_{00}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $\sum_{j=1}^\infty x_j$ be a convergent series in $c_{00}$. Define the seminorm as $||\cdot ||_1$. In a finite case
$$\lvert|\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\rvert|_1\leq \sum_{k=1}^n||x_k||_1$$
I'd believe it. Is the same necessarely valid for countable case?

E: Please delete, nonsensical gibberish

Answer (score 1):

The seminorm is continuous, and so you can pass to the limit as $n\to\infty$ in this inequality.

Comment: Hang on a second, $||\cdot ||_1$ is not a bounded seminorm in $c_{00}$, is it? Boundedness and continuity are equivalent, no?

Comment: Please clarify the definition of $||\cdot||_1$.

Comment: $||x||_1 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty |\xi _k|, x\in c_{00}, x = (\xi _1, \xi _2,\ldots, \xi _n, 0, 0,\ldots )$

Comment: And how the convergence in $c_{00}$ is defined?